# PyQGIS - QComboboxes reciprocally exclusive

Tags: python, pyqgis, combo-box

I build a `QGIS` plugin with 2 `QComboBox`. These comboboxes are populated with the same list of values. Those values come from a query to a `PostgreSQL` database.

When I select a value in the first list, I wan't to remove this value in the second and reciprocally. I started with a signal-slot config and `currentIndexChanged()`. When I select a value in list A, it's removed in list B. But when I select an other value afterwards in list A, first selection is still removed in list B.

How to build reciprocally exclusive and dynamic lists ?

Here is my actual script:

```
# Configuration when plugin is loaded

class myPluginDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog, FORM_CLASS):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):        
        super(myPluginDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        # Connect to database and query to build list of values        
        conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='my_db' port = '5432' host='localhost' user='my_user' password='my_password'")
        cur = conn.cursor()
        sql = """SELECT code FROM public.test GROUP BY code ORDER BY code;"""
        cur.execute(sql)        
        result = cur.fetchall()
        
        list_code = []
        for i in result:
            list_code.append(str(i).replace('(', '').replace(')', '').replace("'", '').replace(',', '')) 
        
        # Populate comboboxes with list_code
        for i in list_code:
            self.comboBox_A.addItem(str(i))
            self.comboBox_B.addItem(str(i))
            
        # Set drop-down lists by default
        self.comboBox_A.setCurrentIndex(-1)
        self.comboBox_B.setCurrentIndex(-1)

        # Signal-Slot config 
        self.comboBox_A.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.sl_change_A)
        self.comboBox_B.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.sl_change_B)

def sl_change_A(self):
    A_index = self.comboBox_A.currentIndex()
    self.comboBox_B.removeItem(A_index)

def sl_change_B(self):
    B_index = self.comboBox_B.currentIndex()
    self.comboBox_A.removeItem(B_index)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested it but something along these lines should work, you just have to save the previously selected element of both combobox so you can restore their previous state on change

```py
# Configuration when plugin is loaded

class myPluginDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog, FORM_CLASS):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):        
        super(myPluginDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self._current_A = None
        self._current_B = None

        # Connect to database and query to build list of values        
        conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='my_db' port = '5432' host='localhost' user='my_user' password='my_password'")
        cur = conn.cursor()
        sql = """SELECT code FROM public.test GROUP BY code ORDER BY code;"""
        cur.execute(sql)        
        result = cur.fetchall()
        
        list_code = []
        for i in result:
            list_code.append(str(i).replace('(', '').replace(')', '').replace("'", '').replace(',', '')) 
        
        # Populate comboboxes with list_code
        for i in list_code:
            self.comboBox_A.addItem(str(i))
            self.comboBox_B.addItem(str(i))
            
        # Set drop-down lists by default
        self.comboBox_A.setCurrentIndex(-1)
        self.comboBox_B.setCurrentIndex(-1)

        # Signal-Slot config 
        self.comboBox_A.activated.connect(self.sl_change_A)
        self.comboBox_B.activated.connect(self.sl_change_B)

    def sl_change_A(self):
        A_text = self.comboBox_A.currentText()
        if self._current_A is not None and self._current_A != A_text:
            self.comboBox_B.addItem(self._current_A)
        self.comboBox_B.removeItem(self.comboBox_B.findText(A_text))
        self._current_A = A_text
        
        # Sort alphabetically
        self.comboBox_A.model().sort(0)

    def sl_change_B(self):
        B_text = self.comboBox_B.currentText()

        if self._current_B is not None and self._current_B != B_text:
            self.comboBox_A.addItem(self._current_B)
        self.comboBox_A.removeItem(self.comboBox_A.findText(B_text))
        self._current_B = B_text

        # Sort alphabetically
        self.comboBox_B.model().sort(0)
```

Comment: Just a question: in `current[0]`, `current[1]` what is `current` ? Because I don't see it before

Comment: My bad, I edited my answer it wasn't supposed to be just `current`

Comment: Ok I understand. Logic seems good but when I deployed it: after a selection in list A and a selection in list B, when I wan't to change selection in list B, QGIS freeze, crash and close. I take a look if I can find a log.

Comment: I fixed the issue now it will work however it only works if all items in combobox are unique, notice that i changed your signals, you used the wrong one (at least for this use case)

Comment: Ok with this method. It seems ok (QGIS doesn't crash anymore). Maybe a last thing: how to sort list in alphabetical order ? Because when user make several selection in lists, values are added at the end, despite of original alphabetical order.

Comment: Don't care about my last comment, I found a way to sort data and completed your answer (`self.comboBox_A.model().sort(0)`). Thanks for all.